# Apache tomcat startup

Tags: tomcat, batch-file

I am trying to start up the tomcat server throug command prompt, but its showing `CATALINE_HOME` variable is not set. I have set the variable by going to control panel then also the same error is coming.

If I directly go to `starttup.bat` file and try to run it, it just blinks and goes. So I tried adding pause command at the end and then when I run I get

```
using CATALINA _BASE :"C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26"
using CATALINA _HOME:"C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26"
using CATALINA _TMPDIR :"C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\temp"
using JRE_HOME :"C:\programfiles\java\jre"
using CLASSPATH :"C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\bin\bootstrap.jar;"C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
```

this is the recent catalog content.

```
    ... 17 more
Dec 12, 2012 3:59:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 12, 2012 3:59:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 445 ms
Dec 12, 2012 3:59:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 12, 2012 3:59:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
Dec 12, 2012 3:59:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\webapps\docs
Dec 12, 2012 3:59:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\webapps\examples
Dec 12, 2012 3:59:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\webapps\host-manager
Dec 12, 2012 3:59:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\webapps\manager
Dec 12, 2012 3:59:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\webapps\ROOT
Dec 12, 2012 3:59:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 12, 2012 3:59:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 468 ms
Dec 12, 2012 4:01:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 12, 2012 4:01:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 12, 2012 4:01:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Dec 12, 2012 4:01:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 12, 2012 4:01:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 12, 2012 4:01:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 12, 2012 4:01:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Comment: Now CATALINA_HOME variable is set but when i run it , it shows the the above error which i was getting by running it through command prompt.

Comment: Are you sure tomcat is not running on the background? Have you tried to connect to http://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: When i am using port 8080 and trying to start from eclipse it shows "8080 port is already in use...startup failed".but when i change the port number it shows the same error.and when running localhost:8080.."it shows http 400 bad request .

Comment: Use any IDE to start up tom cat server

Comment: I used eclipse and got the above erorrs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Tomcat 7.0.40 disappears after 1 second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851818/apache-tomcat-7-0-40-disappears-after-1-second)

Answer (score 0):

That is problably because the process already run in the background. Call `shutdown.bat` to stop it if necessary.

Otherwise you should be able to access that manager at `http://localhost:8080/html/manager`. 
Before doing that you might need to configure a user/password first then restart tomcat.

See [tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access) to learn more about it.

Comment: I called shutdown.bat file ..and then restarted successfully .but when i am running my jsp progrm from eclipse it showing error.  "apache tomcat at local host failed to start".

Comment: When i am trying with http://localhost:8080/html/manager it shows "http 400 bad request"

Comment: Could you look the of content of `$Tomcat/logs/catalina.out` for more logs ?

Comment: I have added the recent content of the catalina logfile .I couldn't make out the problem.

Comment: `INFO: Server startup in 468 ms` seems right. Are you sure your application is deployed ?

Comment: I have changed the port no and the server has started .Can see through localhost:1977, but again when i am trying to run my application in eclipse it shows that " All ports 8080,8005 ,1977 required by tomcat is already in use ".

Comment: You seems to be starting multiple instance of tomcat at the same time. Does Eclipse attempt to start a new tomcat? If so, that is probably why you have this error. What happens when you run the application in eclipse without tomcat running in the background?

Comment: It shows server at "localhost failed to start".I went to run -> run on server in eclipse after shuting down the server.

Comment: It does not seems related to your application but rather to the tomcat configuration in Eclipse. Could you try to start the server alone, using Window > Show view > Other ... and choose Servers. Any other information from the logs would be useful (probably in `$Tomcat/logs/catalina.out`)

Comment: when i try to start the server directly it displays "server at local host faied to start " and there is no catilina.out log file created .I got the log from the error log window ,i am pasting it in above .kindly refer and please tell me what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define two variables first

1. Java_Home
2. CATALINA_HOME

Following is the bat file you can use
here `%TOMCAT_LOC%` = your tomcat path (please don't include bin)

```
echo Stopping Tomcat App Server
cd /D %TOMCAT_LOC%
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\jdk echo java Path
set CATALINA_HOME=%TOMCAT_LOC%
call %TOMCAT_LOC%\bin\shutdown.bat
echo Stopped Tomcat
```

Answer (score -1):

you could move to the path containing the batch file (tomcat/bin), and then run the batch file

C:\Users>cd C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin

C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin>startup.bat

Comment: What problem will this solve? How do you know he isn't already doing this?

Comment: yeah, sorry. You're right, I don't know what I was thinking when I answered this 7 years ago