# Apache Tomcat 7.0.40 disappears after 1 second

Tags: tomcat7

I downloaded apache-tomcat-7.0.40 for Windows 8 and I followed the instructions by using the `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.40> startup.bat` at my command prompt. The tomcat application appeared  for 1 second and then disappeared, so I maybe the documents installation is not enough?
What should I do? While my local host is internet information service.

Comment: Open a terminal / command prompt, go to the directory and then run startup.bat. Check if you see any errors.  You can also check the catalina.out file under the logs folder.  My guess is that you don't have the current version of JDK installed or JAVA_HOME env variable is not set properly.

Comment: Bat file complete its task and cmd window close then. To see what it says either open command propmt in this folder and run up.bat from it or redirect .bat output to text file `up.bat > out.txt`

Comment: Try right-clicking and "run as administrator", solved it for me

Answer (score 32):

In command prompt run below command, you will get the root cause.

```
...\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\bin> catalina.bat run
```

Answer (score 10):

In my case it was because I run `catalina.bat start` and this command creates new command prompt, while `catalina.bat run` executes in the same command prompt and doesn't close it after finishing.

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove the slash at the end of CATALINA_HOME variable path.

Answer (score 3):

Catalina needs `JAVA_HOME` to work properly. So configure path to java jre and `JAVA_HOME` in environment variables.

To see the error, in command prompt execute

```
\path\apache-tomcat-6.0.41\bin > catalina.bat run
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your tomcat/bin folder. Edit startup.bat file, comment out last but one line which says:

```
call "%EXECUTABLE%" run >..\logs\OutputFile.log 2>&1 start %CMD_LINE_ARGS% run >..\logs\OutputFile.log 2>&1
```

comment out using 'rem' beginning of it.

```
rem call "%EXECUTABLE%" run >..\logs\OutputFile.log 2>&1 start %CMD_LINE_ARGS% run >..\logs\OutputFile.log 2>&1
```

then Console will be remain open. if this line is commented then that means it says to close the console and write the output in some external log file.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, most likely, wrong path of the `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable.

Answers above would help, but I will add one point, which would be more extensive as it may help for different kind of exceptions connected to server startup, and namely - to `CATALINA_HOME`.

In the late versions of **`Tomcat`**, You actually do not need to set environment variable `CATALINA_HOME`. If you'll have a look inside start `startup.bat`, the script sets it itself upon each execution.

[23-30] lines of the script in `Tomcat 9`:

```
rem Guess CATALINA_HOME if not defined
set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
set "CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%"
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome
cd ..
set "CATALINA_HOME=%cd%"
cd "%CURRENT_DIR%"
```

So, just to be safe that your environment variable doesn't mess up with something defined by Tomcat script `startup.bat` (or anything else), you can either:

1. Remove your **`CATALINA_HOME`** environment variable entirely, as long as you start your server with `startup.bat`;
2. Correct your environment variable `CATALINA_HOME` path if you insist to be starting it otherwise, and make sure, nothing overrides it during run-time.